# Unique pandas dataframe issue. I want to remove the newline but "/n" exist within the entry

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As said above, I want to fix the following text output from this:

[image: Incorrect Print of Table]

to this:

[image: Correct Print of Table]

Though the pandas list can be indexed properly, the print output is essential to the code that I am writing.

Or from this:

```
             0                 1
0  Application          Password
1       Amazon  3H@)G<1!*ly[go><
2         Hulu  >&c3HX
                      \074Iq<VW
3      YouTube  ~NR\ng
                      X.VkAjqVa
```

To this:

```
         0                 1
1   Amazon  3H@)G<1!*ly[go><
2     Hulu  >&c3HX\074Iq<VW
3  YouTube  ~NR\ngX.VkAjqVa
```

The values are being read in from a csv, and converted to a dataframe.

Cant remove any instance of "\n" as the strings are generated randomly and the option of having a "\" and "n" next to each other cannot be removed.

All I am doing is this to print the dataframe:

```
print(table)
```

What I have tried:

```
table = table.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

Also tried this:

```
print(table.to_string())
```

Result:

```
             0                 1
0  Application          Password
1       Amazon  3H@)G<1!*ly[go><
2         Hulu  >&c3HX
                      \074Iq<VW
3      YouTube   ~NR g
                      X.VkAjqVa
```

Any tips on how to remediate this issue?

Comment: The character `\n` (new line) is different from the two characters ```\``` and `n`. It looks like the passwords actually contain line breaks but since you don't provide the original data, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.